# need to left join in N1QL,Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have below json

**1)**

```
"Cronresult|12":{

      "_type": "DailyCampaignUsage",
      "bids": [
        {
          "clicks": 3,
        }
      ],
      "campaignId": 2614,
}
```

**2).a**

```
"campaign|2614"{
"country": 14,
 "_id": 2614,
}
```

**2).b**

```
"campaign|31"{
"country": 12,
 "_id": 31,
}
```

I am trying below query

```
SELECT Campaign.country,count(DISTINCT Campaign._id) campaigns,
SUM(ARRAY_SUM(DailyCampaignUsage.`statistics`[*].clicks)) clicks,
FROM Inheritx DailyCampaignUsage  
JOIN Inheritx Campaign ON KEYS ('Campaign|'||TOSTRING(DailyCampaignUsage.campaignId))       
where  DailyCampaignUsage._type='DailyCampaignUsage'
```

it is bring below **result**

```
{
    "country": "14",
    "campaigns": 2614,
    "clicks":3 
    }
```

**BUT**

I need output like below

```
    {
   "country": "12",
   "campaigns": 31,
   "clicks":0
    },
    {
    "country": "14",
    "campaigns": 2614,
    "clicks":3 
    },
```

I need to here **RIGHT JOIN** like MySQL.

Can I do it here in **N1QL** ??

if Yes then how can I do it ??

Comment: N1QL only provides LEFT JOIN. Can you reorder your query?

Comment: no I can not i need data then I need to join with country and then user. How can I change my order ??

Comment: Yes, you can solve this with a LEFT OUTER JOIN in N1QL. See https://dzone.com/articles/join-faster-with-couchbase-index-joins